# ¿Cómo encontrar las citas programadas para un día del año?

Tags: python, archivo

Estoy realizando un código en el que inscribo personas para citas en una tienda.

Al momento de escribir la fecha en modo (5-11-2020) al seleccionar la opción 2 el programa me debe mostrar las personas inscritas para ese día, pero no logro hacerlo. Espero puedan ayudarme,

```
print("Bienvenido a la tienda")
print("1)-agregar cita\n2)-mostrar disponibilidad")
opcion = input("elija una opcion:  ")
if opcion == "1":
    archivo = open("tienda.txt", "a")
    print("A continuacion ingrese los datos correspondientes para agendar una cita")
    nombre = input("Nombre cliente:")
    apellido = input("Apellido cliente: ")
    fecha = input("Fecha de trabajo: ")
    trabajo = input("Tipo de trabajo: ")
    print(fecha,nombre,apellido,trabajo, file=archivo)
    archivo.close()
    print("")
    print("Su cita a sido guardada con excito!")
elif opcion == "2":
    archivo = open("tienda.txt", "r")
    print("Ingrese la fecha a visualizar: ")
    disponibilidad= input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para leer varias lineas, necesitas ir iterando por ellas, hay varias soluciones cualquier tipo de bucle es valido, incluso un `yield from` es lo más elegante.

Te dejo una solución sencilla:

```
print("Bienvenido a la tienda")
print("1)-agregar cita\n2)-mostrar disponibilidad")
opcion = input("elija una opcion:  ")

if opcion == "1":
    archivo = open("tienda.txt", "a")
    print("A continuacion ingrese los datos correspondientes para agendar una cita")
    nombre = input("Nombre cliente:")
    apellido = input("Apellido cliente: ")
    fecha = input("Fecha de trabajo: ")
    trabajo = input("Tipo de trabajo: ")
    print(fecha,nombre,apellido,trabajo, file=archivo)
    archivo.close()
    print("")
    print("Su cita a sido guardada con excito!")
elif opcion == "2":
    archivo = open("tienda.txt", "r")

    lines = []
    for line in archivo:
        lines.append(tuple(line.split(" ")))
    disponibilidad= input("Ingrese la fecha a visualizar: ")

    for line in lines:
        if line[0] == disponibilidad:
            print(" ".join(line))
```

### Explicación:

Te dejo explicado por orden lo que vamos aplicando, por si tienes dudas.

- `for`: iteramos por las lineas que hay en el archivo de películas
- `.split()`: es un método que tiene los **strings** que sirve para separarlos en una lista por el caracter indicado, en este caso yo he puesto que sea un espacio `" "`
- `.append()`: sirve para añadir un elemento al final de una lista
- `if` line[0] == disponibilidad`: un condicional en el que le decimos que vaya al elemento en la posición 0, que es la fecha, y si es igual que la fecha introducida haga un` print()` de la película
- `" ".join()`: como con `.split(" ")` previamente separamos por espacios, ahora si queremos imprimirlo todo junto, **necesitamos juntarlo** por lo que llamamos a este método y le indicamos que queremos usar el mismo espacio por el que habíamos separado, para ahora juntar, lo hacemos así: `" ".join(line)"

¡Y ya estária! Hemos leido el archivo, iterado por cada linea y comprobado si la fecha es la ingresada por un usuario.